# how to compare contents of video files?

Tags: video, unix-utils

I have many videos with different encoding. I know some of them have the same content. So here's my need: is there a linux tool (command line oriented, with or without graphical front-end, open-source) to compare the content of video files in a directory ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MediaInfo to get a variety of data on each file, such as container, codec, duration, resolution, etc.

http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en